# When i tried to bevel, half is happening outside and another half is happening inside of the object

Tags: bevel

As u can see in the picture when i tried to bevel the circle, half is happening inside while other half half is outside

What was mistake i have done to make this happen and how to recover from this situation?

[Link to Blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/VnWwj44w)

[image]

Comment: Not sure how you modelled that object, but you have hundreds of overlapping vertices plus the fact that all the faces of the entire model are inverted! In Edit mode, select All > M > Merge by distance, then open the settings in the bottom-left corner and increase the merge distance to .0200. You'll then be able to bevel without problem. Shift > N will correct the inverted faces and you'll need to do that on the 3 key objects too.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked like magic

Comment: You're welcome. I can only imagine that you extruded that circle of verts a couple of times without actually moving them when you were creating the bell of the trumpet because there were at least 3 sets of vertices sitting on top of each other where you were trying to bevel.